# How can i get Array from array of associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I am getting the first array by:
      // $data is fetched information from database
      // like select bookId from book;

```
$json  = json_encode($data);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

I have an array like this: Array of Associative array.

```
0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'bookId' => int 3
1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'bookId' => int 4
2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'bookId' => int 5
3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'bookId' => int 6
```

What i need is simple array:

```
0 => 3      
1 => 5
2 => 6
3 => 6
```

I do want to simple use a for loop. Is there any other good way to do this?

Comment: `$simpleArray = array_column($originalArray, 'bookId');`

Comment: @MarkBaker only for PHP 5.5+

Comment: @MateiMihai which should be a minimum version PHP That you're running anyway these days... if poster doesn't specifically mention a version, then I have to assume they're running a supported version

Comment: It should.. but it doesn't :) 5.3 and 5.4 are more than 60% https://wordpress.org/about/stats/

Comment: foreach ($data as $key => $value) {$newArr[] = $value['bookis'];} try

Comment: Mark Baker thanks. This is what i needed.

Comment: @MateiMihai - so you're saying that I have to provide a solution that will work for all versions of PHP? How far back do I have to go? PHP 5.0? earlier? I can't suggest solutions that use functions/syntax that is available in all current versions of PHP, but not in earlier versions?

Comment: @MateiMihai - IMO, if poster is running an earlier version of PHP than any of the supported versions, then the onus is on them to indicate that fact

Comment: No.. Please don't understand me wrongly.. All I wanted to say was that the most frequent PHP versions are lower than 5.5 and I've just noticed that if there is no explicitly tag with the real version used, then the version is lower than 5.5. I really like your solution and for sure I am using it as well.. What I've commented first was just an addition for others to know in which version your solution works..